# Running Controller Logic without a View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I seem to be hitting a Rails conceptual roadblock. I'm currently using a button_to command to place a button on my show page (standard scaffold). Upon pressing this button, I want to run some code from the controller, and then return to the show page. The problem is that everything I encounter seems to indicate that I have to have a view matching the action in my controller. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

In the controller's action that runs when the button is clicked, just do:

```
redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => X
```

Or, depending on your requirements:

```
render :action => 'show'
```

Comment: This. No need for a view if the method redirects to/renders another method's content